# Средства выражения категории числа

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, в слове "ребёнок" средством выражения категории множественного числа является только супплетивизм (дети) или, наряду с супплетивизмом, ещё морфологическое средство (ребёнок - нулевое окончание, дети - окончание -и)?

В словах "датчанин-датчане" может быть словообразовательное средство выражение категории множественного числа, если суффикс "ин" в единственном числе исчезает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 В словах "датчанин-датчане" может быть словообразовательное средство 
 выражение категории множественного числа, если суффикс "ин" в единственном числе исчезает?
```

Категория числа выражается морфологическими (ручка – ед. ч., ручки – мн. ч.), синтаксическими (эта кенгуру – эти кенгуру), словообразовательными (телёнок – телята) средствами.

В некоторых словах **формы единственного и множественного числа образуются от разных формообразующих основ** (медвежонок-> медвежата, горожанин -> горожане, стул -> стулья, кум -> кумовья, дно-> донья, судно -> суда, курица -> куры).

Датч**анин** – датч**ан**е. Средства выражения категории числа - окончания и усечённые основы (датчанин - датчан). Оба средства **морфологические.**

```
  в слове "ребёнок" средством выражения категории множественного числа является
  только супплетивизм (дети) или, наряду с супплетивизмом, ещё морфологическое 
  средство (ребёнок - нулевое окончание, дети - окончание -и)?
```

Обычно указывают **только супплетивизм**, потому что иначе мы будем сравнивать две парадигмы, ведь супплетивизм - объединение в общую парадигму слов, которые ранее принадлежали к разным парадигмам. «Ребенок – дети»: ранее в единственном числе употребляли «дитя», а к слову "ребёнок" есть пара "ребята". Просто слово "дитя" стало редко употребляться в живой речи, как и "ребята" и две парадигмы сошлись в паре "ребёнок - дети".

А вот в паре "дитя-дети" окончание -и, конечно, будет морфологическим средством выражения множественного числа.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!